# How to list all files with white spaces the after php tag

Tags: php, regex, linux, shell, command

Is it possible with linux commands to List all files with white spaces the after php tag at the end of file?

Comment: A better plan: remove all closing tags.

Comment: +1 to @karim79. The closing tags at the end of a PHP file are optional, and removing them completely resolves the issue of stray whitespace.

Comment: Maybe the OP needed the command to find out which files needed the `?>` removing from them ;)

Comment: @karim79 I've around 11581 files, need to find which one is having the trailing white space in it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Answer using [pcregrep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pcregrep) which will match even if your whitespace spans onto new lines:

```
pcregrep -rM '\?>[\s]+[^\S]*$' *.php
```

Untested though because I don't have pcregrep installed on this computer. Please correct me if you know it to be incorrect.

This should match all files that end with `?>` followed by only whitespace. If it's followed by any other character, then it won't match (e.g. if it's not an all-PHP file and needs `?>`)

Answer (score 1):

Delete all trailing blank lines at end of file.

`sed -i -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;};/\n$/ba' file`

Check for files with whitespace after the closing tag using `grep -El '.*\?>\s+' *.php`:

```
$ cat -E nospace.php
<?php$
?>$
$

$ cat -E withspace.php
<?php$
?>     $
$

$ grep -El '.*\?>\s+' *.php
withspace.php
```

Comment: This won't work if your whitespace is on a new line, which is also going to cause PHP errors if the ending `?>` hasn't been removed. For that, I think you need to use pcregrep instead.

Comment: @Maccath Ahh yes, updated my answer with a solution not using `pcregrep` by using `sed` to remove trailing blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted as a comment:

A better plan: remove all closing tags.

Comment: Whilst this may be a good solution in general, it doesn't answer the OP's original question. He specifically wants to know how to find trailing whitespace in php files. His situation may not even permit him to start modifying the code to the extent of removing the closing php tag from every file. We don't know what his situation is. I found your comment in his post was sufficient, but it's for sure not "the answer". :-)